# Unable to Click on Continue button - Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Unable to Click a link using Selenium - Webdriver: Chrome:Win7

Following is the code when i inspect the button:

> a id="continue_button" disabled="false" class="button button-large ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" href="#" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
>
> span class="ui-button-text">
> span class="button-content">Continue

I have tried the following ways and nothing works:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='continue_button']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(..,'Continue')]")).click();
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("document.querySelector(\"a[id$='continue_button']\").click()");
```

Comment: wait for the button try first in debug and then try to click  driver.verify().verifyElementPresent(by)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the link is partially hidden in DOM.  You can try clicking hidden (or partially hidden) elements using the code snippet below.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='continue_button']));
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
options=driver.find_elements_by_class_name("button-content")
for i in options:
    if(i.text=="Continue"):
        i.click()
```

The above code is in python.Try the above code by translating into java and i hope it will work perfect... any queries let me know.

Comment: If you're wanting more than one element, you'd need to use `.find_elements_by_class_name()` for a list to iterate over like presented here.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this,

```
new WebDriverWait(driver,60).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("#continue_button span.button-content"))).click();
```

The above code will wait for 60 secs for the elements visibilty, if located ,element will be clicked else an exception will be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(driver.getTitle().contains("Error"))
    driver.navigate().to("javascript:document.getElementById('overridelink').click()");
```

Comment: It's better if you explain *why* your code solves the problem. See [answer].

Answer (score -1):

hey do check whether the button lies in a frame or not..